# How to show commits for a specific date?

Tags: git

Is there by any chance a more concise command to get commits for a specific date than for example the expression below?

```
git log --after="2014-09-02 00:00:00" --before="2014-09-02 23:59:59"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an alias.

```
git config --global alias.logondate '!f() { git log --after "$1 00:00:00" --before "$1 23:59:59"; }; f'
```

Than you can use it

```
git logondate 2014-09-02
```

You should also read [Haacked's blog post about git aliases](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/07/28/github-flow-aliases/). It contains a lot of useful examples.

Comment: Better adding --global so that the command is not restricted to the repository you're in.

Comment: @Raffael this command places a line in a .gitconfig file under [alias] section. So it is already persisted. See https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use unix timestamps, these are a bit shorter :)

```
git log --after=1409608800 --before=1409695199
```

Comment: O_o very concise indeed